# Matrix dimensions must agree, Index exceeds matrix dimensions

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing, plot, matlab-figure

I have the following code for  positioning some subplots:

```
fig = figure;
fig.Units = 'centimeters';
fig.Position(3:4) = [25  25];
plotPositions = [ 3, 21,  7,  7;
                 12, 21,  7,  7;  
                ];
nPlots=length(plotPositions);  % shorthand variable for convenience
hAx=zeros(nPlots,1);           % preallocate array for axes/subplot handles
for i = 1:length(plotPositions)
    plotHandle = subplot(3, 2, i);
    plotHandle.Units = 'centimeters';
    plotHandle.Position = plotPositions(i,:);
    hAx(i)=subplot(3, 2, i);  
    axis(hAx(i),[ -300 300 0 150]); %
end
```

If I use

```
plotPositions = [ 3, 21,  7,  7;
                 12, 21,  7,  7;
                  3, 12,  7,  7;
                 12, 12,  7,  7;
                  3,  3,  7,  7;
                 12,  3,  7,  7];
```

it works, but if use

```
plotPositions = [ 3, 21,  7,  7;
                 12, 21,  7,  7;  
                ];
```

it does not work, and I'm getting the error:

```
Matrix dimensions must agree.

Index exceeds matrix dimensions.
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't be using the function `length` but instead the function `size(...,1)` to count the rows of `plotPositions`. `length` is actually `max(size(vec))`, which is `6` (number of **rows**, correctly) in the "working" case, and `4` (number of **columns**) in the non-working one.

Thus, in the 2<sup>nd</sup> case you're actually trying to access "nonexistent" rows, so MATLAB complains....

Comment: @Mueller You're welcome. You can also further explanation [here](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/973/common-mistakes-and-errors/27689/using-length-for-multidimensional-arrays#t=201701241200164448198).